# Is it ok to ask for the availability of a RPi housing?

Tags: support, on-off-topic

Is it ok to ask for a vendor who sells RPi housings?

I'm looking for a housing that takes the 7" touch screen and is thus similar to the Multicomp CBRPP-TS-BLK/WHT housing. However, I'd like to be able to access the SD card and have a slot for wiring GPIOs.

Is such a specific request on topic?

<sub>I found a better and cheaper housing than the Multicomp, which gives access to the GPIO pins: https://www.rasppishop.de/ModMyPi-Raspberry-Pi-7-Touch-Display-Gehaeuse-Schwarz but the SD card can still not be accessed.</sub>

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic per site rules. That makes your question at least, well how to put it, bordering off-topic.

Comment: I guess this a  topic for the hardware recommendations stack exchange.